# .htaccess - how to rewrite url without parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url, permalinks

Hi i've got another question

i have the simplest htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

it gives me friendly urls eg. www.mysite.loc/blog/

but i want to go further and have eg. `www.mysite.loc/blog/?page=1` and `www.mysite.loc/blog/?page=1&id=1`

how can i do that ?

P.S. i've tried many solutions that i've found in google but nothing works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1&%{query_string} [L]
```

This way, a request for `/blog/?page=1` would get mapped to `/index.php?url=/blog/&page=1` and `/blog/abc/?page=3` would get mapped to `/index.php?url=/blog/abc/&page=3`.

You'd then parse `$_GET['url']` to figure out what resource the browser asked for.

Comment: thanx @grossvogel your post helped me :)